# Compare url in django

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to hide a content when a user is visiting his own profile. I tried the code below but it didn't work. What could be wrong.

```
 {% if request.path == "/account/users/{{ request.user.username }}/" %}

  {% else %}

<img src="https://tyllplus.com/static/arrow-orange-down-vector-1.png" width="30" height="30">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: If that is a profile detail view, you surely have the `user` of the profile object readily available as a context variable.

Comment: Although you *can* do that in the template, it is not where it belongs, you better add this to the *view*.

Comment: @Willem I'd like to know how to achieve it that way. could you elaborate a bit further?

Comment: @kingiyk: it is already in the answer. You will somehow have passed the `user` you render (or you should), for example by passing through the context data a variable with name `my_user`, and then check it in the template.

Comment: thnx for your help. I solved it with this {% if request.user.username in request.path %} just in case any body needs it.

Comment: better yet, {% if request.user.get_absolute_url == request.path %}

Answer (score 2):

(Advanced) string processing should not be done in the template. Especially not with URLs, since you might later want to change the view. Even if you manage to get it work, if you later have a prefixed path, it can start failing. This method would also heavily depend on the format of the URL: if you later specify a URL where you use the `id` instead of the `username`, then you will need to look for all all URL processing that depends on this format. This is not elegant design.

Of course simple processing is no problem. For example adding comma separators to a number, etc. is typically handled by template tags. But URLs - in my opinion - do not really fit in that category.

You better encode this logic in the *view* (or make sure that you easily can detect it with elements from the view).

For example for a `DetailView`:

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserDetailView(DetailView):
    model = User
    context_object_name = 'my_user'
    template = 'user_detail.html'
```

We know that the `my_user` variable will carry the `User` object ot display, so then we can verify with:

```
{% if my_user != request.user %}
<!-- show something -->
{% else %}
<!-- show something else -->
{% endif %}
```